# migration.conf file while installing splunk universal forwarder

Tags: installation, splunk

Please let me know what exactly is migration.conf file created during installation of splunk UF ?

```
File path : /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/migration.conf
```

Thanks in Advance,
NVP

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the contents of the file?  It shows what Splunk did when a new version of the forwarder was installed.  When the new version runs for the  first time, a number of checks are run and files may be modified or removed.  The migration.conf file lists each action that was performed.

It's a good idea to review this log after each upgrade, because it may identify local changes that override new features.